# How to undo a vote?

Tags: support, votes, undo

Today, I accidentally up voted an answer, while intending to up vote *another* answer.

To undo this, I hit the down vote button, but after that, I had down voted the answer.

So I up voted it again, because I felt sorry for the author.

Question: is there no way to *undo* a down or up vote on an answer?

Comment: That's confusing. Joel's answer has no downvotes.

Comment: Indeed, now it shows that I have *up voted* his answer. Must have been a fluke ... I'll reduce this question to merely asking how to undo a vote. I cannot find that question in the db.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you realize your mistake immediately you should be able to undo an upvote by clicking upvote a second time (at least it works for me); similarly for a downvote. (Try it on my answer here -- click upvote, say "oops, didn't mean that", then click *up* a second time and the vote should come back off again. Then click upvote a third time because *my answer is just the greatest, we have the best answers, everyone thinks so*.)

It may seem a little counterintuitive at first but once you get used to it, it will seem fairly natural.

If you don't realize you want to change your vote fairly quickly (more precisely, within [five minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes/5213#5213)), you'll be outside the window in which you can change your mind, in which case your vote will not be changeable until the post is edited.

Comment: I think the last point deserves some additional stressing: after a post is edited (even if the edit is trivially small), everybody can re-vote, i.e. cancel or reverse their previous vote.

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer because the crowds for this answer were bigger than any crowds have ever been for any other answer.

Comment: It is worth adding that vote can be changed if the answer was edited.

Comment: @Tim it already says "your vote will not be changeable until the post is edited" ... right there at the end. To say it again would seem to be redundant

Comment: Theoretically yes but people often do not read those notices...

Comment: Since i have just accidentally down-voted a posting and didn't notice within 5 min, i would find it a good thing to drop the 5-min limit for taking back the voting.